# Python MySQL Standard

Tags: python, mysql

What is the "standard" way of using mysql in python. I define standard as something that won't go away for a long time.

```
import _mysql
db = _mysql.connect(host, user, pass, db); 
db.query("sql");
```

vs

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pass, db); 
cursor = db.cursor(); 
cursor.execute("sql");
```

Obviously MySQLdb is a wrapper for _mysql, but I hate using wrappers at the risk of them not being maintained

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+database

Comment: Why did you use the `_mysql` module?  Where have you seen code like this?

Comment: the _mysql module is based directly off of the C API.. which I'm familiar with.

Comment: `_mysql` comes with `MySQLdb`. If the latter becomes unmaintained then so will the former, therefore your concerns make no sense.

Comment: And *should* they become unmaintained, you're going to have to recode *anyway*, since the alternative implements DB-API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
import MySQLdb
```

Which really isn't supported. On the PC, if you install the latest Python, it can be a problem to find.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of dealing with relational database engines is defined by DB-API as described in [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: In other words, MySQLdb and not _mysql since _mysql doesn't enforce DB-API standards.